# Xaml converter in c# code

Tags: silverlight, xaml, c#-4.0, converters

I have this code :

```
Color color = GetMyColor();
string s = @"<DataTemplate xmlns=""http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation""><StackPanel Background=""" + color + "\" ><TextBlock Text=\"{Binding Label}\"  HorizontalAlignment=\"Center\"   /></StackPanel></DataTemplate>";
var MyObject.Template = (DataTemplate)XamlReader.Load(s);
```

And I would like to add a converter to my binding, somethind like this :

```
Color color = GetMyColor();
string s = @"<DataTemplate xmlns=""http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation""><StackPanel Background=""" + color + "\" ><TextBlock Text=\"{Binding Converter={StaticResource NumberConverter}}\"  HorizontalAlignment=\"Center\"   /></StackPanel></DataTemplate>";
var MyObject.Template = (DataTemplate)XamlReader.Load(s);
```

However, this is not working because I need to add the namespace of my converter I think.

How should I do that ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK,
StaticResource works just by name. It looks Resources. It does not seem namespace problem.

You can easily add your namespace by

```
    @"<DataTemplate xmlns:local=""clr-namespace:YourProjectBus.Converters""
```

Beside this ensure that your staticresource (NumberConverter) added formerly into running 
class. 
It must be done before

```
 var MyObject.Template = (DataTemplate)XamlReader.Load(s);
```

such as

```
  ctor()
{
   this.Resources.Add("NumberConverter",new NumberConverter());
}
```

Inspect output , binding errors displayed in output pane.
Good Luck!